# How to find least value from join table in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter. I had made a function to get all products by joining 4 more tables including price table. I need a lowest price of the product. How to do that???
My code is:-

```
function fetch_all_products()
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('products')
        ->join('reviews','products.ID=reviews.product_id','left')
        ->join('product_price','products.ID=product_price.product_id','left')
        ->join('product_news','products.ID=product_news.product_id','left')
        ->join('websites','websites.ID=product_price.website_id','left')
        ->group_by('products.Name')->order_by('product_price.price','asc')->where('status',1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

I am getting many products and each product has many prices now i have to show each product with lowest price...

Comment: First `where`, then `group` and `order`, I suppose. Does this code work?

Comment: then how it should be

Comment: does the above query works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get just smallest value with `select_min` CI function

```
$this->db->select_min('price');
```

Or with ordering:

```
$this->db->order_by("price", "asc");
$this->db->limit(1);
```

Comment: this all is not working because i am getting many products and each product has many prices now i have to show each product with lowest price...

Answer (score 0):

From that you should get a group of rows with the product that has the lowest price on the first position.

Why don't you just get the price of that first row?

Comment: this all is not working because i am getting many products and each product has many prices now i have to show each product with lowest price...